# Designing a simple database that respects the third normal form

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, database-design

I'm trying to accomplish [3NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form) or third normal form for a small database homework.

I have Students, Classes and Parents.

Here are the tables I need to make:

- **Student:** id, name, grade (avg)
- **Class:** class_id, profile (type of class), class_master, students *within said class*
- **Parent:** name, address, student *enrolled in school*

**Things that I should point out:**

Since my english is not that good, I thought I should specify:

- Class is one to many relationship since one student can be part of one class, and only one (thus a class is a collection of students, nothing else).
- Profile is a specialization of a class (again, the student grouping mechanism called class). *Ex: Profile: Mathematics, Literature, Computer Science*

**[/Things that I should point out]**

Again, I have to make tables that fall within 3NF guidelines, not tables that are exactly like the ones I have just mentioned

I was thinking:

```
Class: 
   class_id primary key, foreign key (class_master_name) 

Profile: 
   class_master_name primary key, profile_name

Student: 
   student_id primary key, name, grade (avg), foreign key (class_id)

Parent: 
   parent_id primary key, name, address
```

Thus Class, Profile, Student and Parent would be 3NF since all non key elements refer strictly to the key, the whole key, and nothing but the key.

**My problems (or rather specific questions that need answers):**

- Is the student <-> class relationship OK ? Is it enough that student refers to class ? I could not imagine a way class could have references towards the students without having repeating data that would either conflict with [2NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form) or [1NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).
- Each student has up to two parents (one, or both could be dead or simply unknown). I was thinking of having a table `Relationship: student_id, parent_1_id, parent_2_id` but I have no idea how to implement this. How could I (in *SQL Server Management Studio 2008*) make this table (where `parent_1_id != parent_2_id` **and also** `student_id` is the `primary key` but also a `foreign key`)
- Would this actually be [3NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form) or am I doing something wrong ?

How I thought of implementing `Relationship: student_id, parent_1_id, parent_2_id`

```
CREATE TABLE Relationship (
     student_id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
     parent_1_id int,
     parent_2_id int,
     CONSTRAINT (parent_1_id, parent_2_id) FOREIGN KEY 
         REFERENCES Parent (parent_id, parent_id),
     CONSTRAINT  (student_id) FOREIGN KEY 
         REFERENCES Student (student_id)
)
```

Is it OK ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need something similar to this:

[image]

*(`Class.ProfileId` and `Student.ClassId` are NOT NULL, while `Parent1Id` and `Parent2Id` are NULL-able.)*

Comment: Could you also provide the code for `Relationship: student_id, parent_1_id, parent_2_id` ? I edited in my version, I just don't know if it's good. I can modify it for Student they way you explained, but I would want (as a proof of concept) the table I mentioned initially. Thank you

Comment: @Kalec It's already there. The relationship between child and mother is N:1. Ditto for child and father. Since this is not M:N, you don't need the additional "junction" or "link" table in between.

Answer (score -1):

```
ClassType:    
classtype (primary key)
name
etc...    

Class:
classid (primary key)
classtype (foreign key)
classname
etc...

Person:
personid (primary key)
name
dob
etc....

ClassStudent:
studentid (primary key)
classid (foreign key)
personid (foreign key)
grade
etc

PersonRelation:
relationid (primary key)
prim_personid (foreign key)
sec_personid (foreign key)
relationship (parent, sibling, etc)
etc
```

Comment: Regards to `PersonRelation` I only need parents, nothing else. I don't see why I'd need a relationid, since this is only to be used in correlation with what the "school" would need, thus student as primary key is fine. But, `ClassStudent` sounds like a good idea but again I don't really get the `personID`. Actually without a bit of explanation I don't [get / agree with] much of anything.

Comment: A Person is either a parent or a student.    You link a Person to a Class with ClassStudent.    You link a parent (Person) to the child (another Person) with a PersonRelation.    This would support other relationships than parent/child.    brother/sister husband/wife, etc.